# How do I know which resources will be loaded for my device?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-hardware, android-resolution

If I have any device at hand, how can I know which resources will be used by my apk?
e.g. `drawable-hdpi` or `drawable-xhdpi` or `drawable-xxhdpi`
I am not asking in theory which of these folders is loaded when but specifically if I have a random device at hand how do I know which will be used?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at some Google results like: [generator](https://www.sven.de/dpi/)
or [explanation](http://www.brandbuildercompany.com/blog/2012/03/29/device-independent-pixel-formula-for-mobile-devices/) if you want to know the 'magic' behind it.

And on the Android development site you can find an overview of the [density buckets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html): Density buckets

If that still doesn't answer your question, you can also take per example a couple of different images per density folder (hdpi, ldpi, mdpi...) and just see which shows on your device or emulator.

Comment: I though/hoped that it would be as simple as checking something in my device's settings to be honest

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand the idea of Density Buckets. Take a look at this image(collected from [here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android))
[image]

So, Below 160 dpi is called `ldpi` and found inside folder `drawable-ldpi`
and below 320 and upto 480 dpi is called `xhdpi` and found inside folder `drawable-xhdpi` etc.

So, which variation will be used solely depends on your phone's screen density. For better understanding take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) article, specially on the Table-1.

To get your phone's density, you can use this code

`final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`

So,If your phone falled under xhdpi category, which is between 320 and 480 dpi, `drawable-xhdpi` variation will be used and so on.

Comment: I though/hoped that to determine the phone's density it would be as simple as checking something in my device's settings to be honest

Comment: sadly no, and I think its okay because, phone's density is developers need to know knowledge, but not average people's.

Comment: So if I google for the device's resolution e.g. OnePlus and I see `1080 x 2340 pixels` can I use that information to figure out the resources to be used at runtime reliably?

Comment: @Jim please ask another question if not directly related to original post. As far as I know, for android PPI and DP are same. so, from screen resolution and device's physical screen size, you can calculate DP or PPI. **PPI = sqrt(height^2 + width^2)/screen_size**

Comment: So why is this not related to the original post? If I know the PPI can't I also know which of the resources are being used? If no, then sure I can open another question

Answer (score 1):

One diagnostic method which is simple is to add a `strings.xml`(or resource type of your choice) to a qualified res/values- directory with a string value corresponding to the density such as in:

```
res/values-xxhdpi
    strings.xml (containing)
        <string name="selected_density">xxhdpi</string>
```

You can do this with other resources types as well such as integer.  This lets the system do the work for you.  Do this for each density of interest and also supply a default in values/ version.

Then in code simply:

```
String densityStr =  context.getString(R.string.selected_density);
```

See `Configuration qualifier names` table here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Comment: So only programmatically we can know?